# flutter firestore push document data to details screen

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to click on the list, and open a new detail page.  I've looked everywhere for examples of how to do this and I found many.  However my data is structured different and even though my code has no errors it will not populate the details page.  Here is what i'm working with:

```
//page 1
child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount:
                                    _documents == null ? 0 : _documents.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return Card(
                                      child: Container(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                                image: AssetImage(
                                                    "assets/images/roomfield1.png"),
                                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter),
                                            color:
                                                Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                                          ),
                                          child: ListTile(
                                              title: Text(_documents[index]
                                                  ['title']),
                                              subtitle: Text(_documents[index]
                                                  ["description"]),
                                              trailing: Text(_documents[index]
                                                  ['citystate']),

                                              onTap: () {
                                              Navigator.push(
                                                  context,
                                                   MaterialPageRoute(
                                                      builder: (context) =>
                                                          DetailPage(_documents[index])));

                                              })));
                                },
```

Here is the details page:

```
// details page
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DetailPage(_documents,  {Key key,}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  var _documents;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title:  Text('Details Page'),
        ),
        body:  ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _documents == null ? 0 : _documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,[index]) {
              return  ListTile(
                title: Text(_documents[index]['title']),
                );
}));}}
```

My documents use the documentId.  i tried passing the id and then using it in a stream builder and that didn't work either.  I think my code is close, but I don't know what is wrong.  Also I cant change the structure of the data, because it is used all over the place in this format.  I'm guessing its something simple that i missed, maybe the constructor on the details page but i'm not sure...Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You created a variable called `_documents` at the top of the class. However, to retrieve the value of the actual `_documents` variable in the `DetailPage` class, you need to use `widget.documents`. I have provided the correct code below for you to use.

Also, I don't know why you're using a `StatefulWidget` for your `DetailPage` class since you don't seem to be doing anything that requires state management. You could easily make this a `StatelessWidget` but maybe there's more code that I'm unable to see.

```
// details page
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final var documents; // created new final variable that will be initialized by the constructor
  DetailPage(this.documents);
  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  //var _documents; // Don't use this
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title:  Text('Details Page'),
        ),
        body:  ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.documents == null ? 0 : widget.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return  ListTile(
                title: Text(widget.documents[index]['title']), // don't know why you need to specify the index since you already did in your other classs
                );
}));}}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Also, You were right, I did not need the index.